# Setting image detection area in Google Cloud Vision API OCR

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I have used Google Cloud Vision API for document text detection, but I could not figure out if it lets us define a particular area of image from which to extract text. 
For example if my image has 3 columns of text and I want to provide top-left coordinates, width and height of a particular column on which I want to perform OCR. Is it possible?
Also is there any other way to not get jumbled up text when we have 3 columns of text in image?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, It is not possible to define a particular area of image from which to extract text. There is no available parameter for that in the image context in neither the [REST](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext) or [gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#imagecontext) APIs. A Possible workaround is to crop your image and send only the text you want to transcript. If you want to try to automate this process, perhaps the [object localization](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer) or the [crop hints](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/crop-hints) features may be of use.

Regarding the jumbled up text, you may be able to locate each block or paragraph in the [Json response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#text_detection_responses).

Comment: Actually there is a `latLongRect` field as part of the request's [`ImageContext`](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext) in the REST API, nevertheless docs indicate that it's not used. So @ch_mike is right but this might allude to the feature appearing sometime in the future.

Comment: @ch_mike So far I have been cropping out the columns and appending them one below the other using imagemagick and sending this vertical one column image to vision API but it is taking a lot of time for image processing.

Comment: @LefterisS Any more details on how to use the `latLongRect` parameter?

Comment: @Naveed, I see the drawbacks of this approach. You may want to open a Feature Request to GCP using this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161131), be sure to include the sufficient information so other users can understand the scenario and vote up, bringing more attention to the request. For the columns issue, there is already a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69242764), please consider voting up by clicking the star next to the issue number.

Answer (score 0):

You can builder your own wrapper class around the Detector class. Then re-build the bitmap in the frame object that gets fed into the detect method.